# On coursera R-programming course Assignment 2 Lexical Scoping

Tags: r

I'm Using Win7 64x Rstudio Version 3.3.2.

The following functions is assignmet2 solution that other people submitted.

```
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
    inv <- NULL
    set <- function(y) {
            x <<- y
            inv <<- NULL
    }
    get <- function() x
    setInverse <- function(inverse) inv <<- inverse
    getInverse <- function() inv
    list(set = set,
         get = get,
         setInverse = setInverse,
         getInverse = getInverse)
}
```

First in the function makeCacheMatrix, why does 'set function' use variable 'y'?
Is it simply used to tell us how to use '<<-'?

Secondly, In 'get function', why is variable 'x' followed by the parentheses of the function? ( 'setInverse function - inv<<-inverse' , 'getInverse function - inv' are the same. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x <<- y` creates `x`, which is then retrieved by `get()`. Note that `get` is also a base function and is being overwritten here. I would advocate in avoiding this, even though it's confined to a function. An *ad hoc* solution would be to reach base `get` function through `base::get`.

Line `get <- function() x` is a "short" version of

```
get <- function() {
  x
}
```

Short version will work if you have only one line or separate statements using `;`. The biggest beef I have with this piece of code is no use of argument. This may be fine with Java or some other language, but I don't consider that an R way. Modifying objects like this can lead to unintended behavior which could lead to painstaking debugging.

`setInverse` and `getInverse` are not the same. What they do is set inverse or get it.

Comment: Thanks to your detailed explanation, I understand the problem. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You know that the goal of this task is to create a super matrix that can store it's content and it's inverse as well. So it has to have 2 variable `x` the matrix, and `inv` the inverse. Each variable has 2 functions `set` and `get`. So, `set` is a function that takes an argument and do something inside it, in this code `set` takes `y` as an argument (dummy variable could be any other name) and assign it to the matrix `x`. The same for `inv`.

This will make the only access for these variables is through `set` and `get`.

Note that:(R documentation)
 `The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned`

Now, if we want to use this function:

```
mat <- makeCacheMatrix()

## set the matrix value
mat$set(matrix(data = (1:10), nrow = 5, ncol = 2))

## Check that we stored it correctly
mat$get()
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    6
# [2,]    2    7
# [3,]    3    8
# [4,]    4    9
# [5,]    5   10
```

Comment: I understand how to use the operator '<<-' for your help. Thank you very much :)

Comment: glad i can help :). This specialization is very useful I am currently taking it. Good luck.